# Eliminating a border effect

Tags: c#, graphics, directx, sharpdx

This is a work project. I inherited some code using SharpDX (a DirectX layer). One of my tasks is to fix a piece of code where certain image effects are applying to a geometric shape containing a fill. If the filter is applied to the fill itself, it doesn't conform to the edges. I've figured out the code to pull out an excerpt using the Geometry of the object. For various reasons, they want to keep the fill that exists outside of the shape (namely, we have some distortion effects that pull in pixels outside of the shape), so I need to overlay it over the background. The problem I'm running into is that I'm getting this single-pixel border...

**Applying the Soft Edge filter to the visible part**
[image: Blurred interior]

**The background with the shape cut out**
[image: Outside image]

**The two composited together in the program**
[image: Composited]

**What I'm actually getting**
[image: What I'm actually getting]

I can't share a good bit of the code, due to parts of it being proprietary, but the mask is a byte array. I'm building it using the following code:

```
SingleChannelBitmap mask = new SingleChannelBitmap(MaxRequiredPixels.Width, MaxRequiredPixels.Height, 255);
mask.FillShape(new RectangleF(new PointF(0,0), mask.Size), this.Geometry, 0);
```

255 is the maximum Alpha value (transparent). I invert it to take the slice out of the background. The only thing I can think of is that, when I do the masking, it's not including the outer edge of the Geometry. I'm going to try expanding the mask by one pixel in the crudest way possible (basically, scanning through and taking anything which is 0 transparency and adding a 0 transparency pixel to the left, right, up, and down), but I know there has to be a more elegant solution.

This has to work for the 3D Edge bevel filter as well, so doing an arbitrarily large whitespace probably won't work for me either.

Comment: It is too unclear what you are doing. If you can't include code, then maybe a formal description of your operations?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is essentially the same haloing problem that sometimes occurs with displaying PNG images. The PNG export process from several programs will store a solid color for any portions of the PNG that has zero alpha, instead of the actual color at those pixels. This makes them function similar to other image formats (GIF) which use a specific color to encode transparent pixels. This significantly reduces the size of the file, however, can cause issues when sampling the image.

Your situation is similar. Although the masked pixels have zero alpha, when doing bilinear sampling, you may sample in between pixels, mixing both color and alpha values (unless pixel and texel centers are perfectly aligned). For example, if you have a 100% alpha, white pixel, next to a 0% alpha red pixel, and sample in between both, the result will be a pink pixel at 50% alpha.

There are several possible solutions:

- You could extend the borders of the color layer, such that the 0% alpha border has the same color as its non-0% alpha adjacent pixels.
- Intentionally line up the pixel and texel centers, although this can be tricky and/or not possible, depending on your requirements (mostly dependent on resolution).
- Use 'nearest' sampling, instead of bilinear when displaying the image. This way, you will never blend in a 0% alpha pixel. However, this may also not be desirable, because your image will likely exhibit more aliasing effects.